# Wildfly subsystem configuration attribute not allowed here

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I would like to set in the WildFly/JBoss [ejb3 subsystem](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/subsystem/ejb3/index.html) `enable-graceful-txn-shutdown` to `true`.

Tried two approaches:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0" enable-graceful-txn-shutdown="true">
```

and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
    <enable-graceful-txn-shutdown value="true"/>
```

Both times I got a *Validation error in standalone.xml*:

> 'enable-graceful-txn-shutdown' isn't an allowed attribute for the
> 'subsystem'
>
> element 'enable-graceful-txn-shutdown' isn't an allowed
> element here

What is the right place?

Comment: Can you confirm you're using Wildfly 11.0.0.Final Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution?

Comment: Using  `wildfly:11.0.0.Final `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subsystem tag's namespace is incorrect, `enable-graceful-txn-shutdown` isn't defined in `urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0` but in `urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0` (which is new in Wildfly 11).

If you check the XSD defining this namespace (which can be found in the `docs/schema` dir of your wildfly install, in this case as the `wildfly-ejb3_3_5_0.xsd` file), you'll find as Omoro pointed out that this tag should be at the root of your subsystem with a `value` boolean attribute, i.e.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
  <enable-graceful-txn-shutdown value="true"/>
```

Comment: To follow up it's better to use CLI so that you don't need to worry about editing the XML. For a standalone server the CLI command would be `/subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name=enable-graceful-txn-shutdown, value=true`